# Vector subspaces of zero dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

I was confused about zero dimension vector subspaces. Can you please answer the following questions with details/examples.

1. What is the dimension and basis for vector space that is just composed of the zero vector.
2. If the answer to the latter is an empty set, how can I construct a zero vector of say n rows from the empty set?
3. Say there are three vector spaces `[0]  [0, 0] [0 ,0, 0]`. What are the basis for them. Isn't just saying empty set led to ambiguity about the zero vector subspace, it is a basis for?

Answer (score 3):

(1) A vector space that is composed of just the zero vector is zero dimensional and its basis is the empty set.

(2) You can construct a zero vector because the empty sum is *defined* to be zero (this is somewhat of a cheat).  The sum $\sum_{v_i\in\emptyset}a_iv_i$ is an empty sum, and it is defined to be the zero element of the vector space.

(3) The vector spaces $\{[0]\}$, $\{[0,0]\}$, and $\{[0,0,0]\}$ are all *isomorphic*, so there really isn't much ambiguity (they are all, in essence the same space).  If you want to use the sum from before, the empty sum valuates to the zero element *in the vector space in which you're working*.

Comment: How can different linear combinations of the zero element to different zero vectors?

Comment: Because you always work in the context of some space, the empty set is a subset of some vector space and you get the zero for that vector space you're working in.

Comment: If possible can you add example to explain this in the answer.

Comment: An example isn't very enlightening.  Let $V$ be a vector space.  The basis $\emptyset\subseteq V$ generates the subspace $\{0\}$ where $0$ is the zero of $V$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof:

Let us assume that $\mathscr B$ is a basis of $\{0\}$.

Then since $\mathscr B$ is a subset of  $\{0\}$ so $\mathscr B=\{0\}$ or $\mathscr B=\emptyset$. If it has to be non-empty then $\mathscr B=\{0\}$

But $\{0\}$ is not linearly independent how can it be a basis.

Comment: The proof makes sense. Can you explain more on empty sum.

Comment: If a set $S$ is empty then the sum of elements of $S$ is defined to be $0$;For more google *empty sum*